# Jquery scroll has to fire more often

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome

I have the code:

```
$(window).bind('scroll', function() {
//doing funny things here
});
```

But I have to fire it a lot when it scrolls, like firefox does.
Firefox fires this multiple times when you scroll, but IE and Chrome fires it only once.
How can I force IE and Chrome to fire it more often in one scroll?
Or is there an alternative way for this?

Comment: try `on` instead of `bind` `$(window).on('scroll', function() { ... });`

Comment: @VitorinoFernandes Doesn't work, still fires it only once in chrome and IE

Comment: I think your problem is that IE at least until v9 I believe does not scroll smoothly. Instead it jumps a couple pixels at once. Firefox scrolls very smooth and fires the event a couple times (since there are a lot of small jumps). IE does a single jump and fires only once.

Comment: @NoelWidmer I'm using the latest version of IE and Chrome, you're correct that they make a jump, and that is my problem, I am trying to find a solution for that and make it fire more often like firefox.

Comment: @Nick I never did this, but you could subscribe to the mousewheel callback in js and manually scroll through the page by adjusting the margin-top of an top-level container. Still, you would somehow have to prevent the default scrolling behaviour and call the scroll event from the browser manually. Are you looking for something like that?

Comment: @NoelWidmer That sounds very complicated and will probably make some issues in some browsers/devices(I think), Isn't there an easier solution for this problem?

Comment: I try http://jsfiddle.net/sn5uca36/ but work, Is right my sample?

Comment: @Fabio Not really, but if you try your fiddle in firefox, and in chrome, you'll see the difference. Chrome fires it only once, and I need it to fire more often per scroll.

Comment: I try in firefox and in chrome the behavior is same. chrome version 37.0.2062.124 and firefox version 30.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a characteristic of the hardware, operating system and browser, nothing you can influence. Firefox has "smooth scrolling" by default, whereas other browsers just jump to the new position in fixed intervals. But then there are also operating system settings you can tune and also other input devices like touch screens and trackpads which have different characteristics.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this with this script.
It creates an interval if there is none every time you scroll and then checks for when the scroll has stopped and terminates. Simply adjust the interval time, currently set to 1ms to what ever interval you require.

```
<script>
    var interval;

    $(window).bind('scroll', function() {
        if(interval == null)
            interval = setInterval(function(){/*funny stuff*/ console.log("scrolling :D")}, 1);
            clearTimeout( $.data( this, "scrollCheck" ) );
            $.data( this, "scrollCheck", setTimeout(function() {
                console.log("stopped");
                clearInterval(interval);
                interval = null;
            }, 250) );
    });                 

</script>
```

**EDIT:**
Optimised script.