# jQuery scrollTop not updating until after scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm having an odd issue that I'm struggling to figure out.

I have a simple, full page, scrolling site where I've tried to mimic position:fixed on certain elements by using jQuery scrollTop to apply a `top` value when the page is scrolled.

This process works fine in Chrome and FF, but in Safari (desktop and iOS) and also Chrome (Android) the scrolling is very jerky.

I've inspected the code in Safari on desktop and it appears that, unlike Chrome & FF, the `scrollTop` value isn't being applied to the `top` until after the scroll has finished, which is causing the jerkiness.

Is this something that can be rectified?

This is the small JS snippet I am using, as well as a link to an example [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/q0dnb1rh/1/)

```
var fullHeight = $(window).height();
$('.panel').height(fullHeight);

$(window).scroll(function () {

    var text = $('.text');
    var textOffset = text.offset();
    var textViewOffset = $(document).scrollTop();

    $('.text').css({
        'top': textViewOffset
    });
    $('.panel:nth-child(2) .text').css({
        'margin-top': -fullHeight
    });
    $('.panel:nth-child(3) .text').css({
        'margin-top': (-fullHeight) * 2
    });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `$(window).scroll(function () { console.log('scrolled'); });` and you'll see that it logs only once in chrome and more often in firefox, that's the problem.

1. In some old chrome browsers you can enable smoothscroll in the settings.
2. Use a smoothscroll plugin.
3. Get rid of `$(window).scroll` and make a function that fires every 1-2millisecond

Comment: Thanks for the tips. JS isn't my strong suit, how would I go about creating a new function that fires every couple of milliseconds?

Comment: @DeanElliott Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26272506/jquery-scroll-has-to-fire-more-often